# Trying to return numbers in a list

Tags: python

I have a few questions about this code here.  What I'm trying to do is write a function that takes 2 inputs, a list and an option, which the option is either 0 or 1, and returns a list of numbers in the list.  If the option is 0, it will return numbers that are greater than 5 or less than -5.  If the option is 1, it will return a list of all the odd numbers on the first list.  This is what I have for code right now:

```
def splitList(myList, option):
    nList = []
    for element in range(0,len(myList)):
        if option == 0:
            if myList[element] > 5:
                nList.append(element)
    return nList
```

Right now I got it to return a list of if the elements are greater than 5, but it returns where they are in the list, not the actually value.  Say I ran the program

```
splitList([-6,4,7,8,3], 0)
```

it would return
    [2, 3]

I want it too return the values of 7 and 8 and also -6 but I know I don't have the right code to return -6 as of now.  Can someone guide me in the right direction.  Also, I want to be using a for loop here.  Also I have no clue how to return odd numbers if the option is 1.

Here is my code which works:

```
def splitList(myList, option):
    nList = []
    for element in myList:
        if option == 0:
            if abs(element) > 5:
                nList.append(element)
        elif option == 1:
            if element % 2:
                nList.append(element)
    return nList
```

How would I be able to switch this to a while loop?
I tried the following code but it does not seem to work:

```
def splitList2(myList, option):
    nList = []
    element = 0 
    while element < len(myList):
        if option == 0:
            if abs(element) > 5:
                nList.append(element)
        elif option == 1:
            if element % 2:
                nList.append(element)
        element = element + 1
    return nList
```

Comment: You have `nList.append(element)` where apparently you want `nList.append(myList[element])`.

Comment: You also need `abs()` or an `or` statement if you want the absolute value greater than 5...

Comment: Odd numbers are numbers for which `number % 2` is not 0.

Comment: BTW, you should get in the habit of accepting an answer to your questions, when people work so hard to solve things for you. (Not me, but others...)

Comment: @beroe I apologize, not familiar with this site and how it runs.

Comment: [This link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) will give you the full story, but basically, once you get a satisfactory answer to your question, click the hollow check mark next to that answer.

Comment: any ideas on how to switch it to a while loop? @beroe

Comment: @RyanErickson: You really should create a new question instead of trying to tack a follow-up onto an existing question. But… your attempt to switch to a `while` loop has the same problem as your original code: You've _called_ your index `element`, but it's still just an index; the actual element is `myList[element]`. I've edited my answer to explain more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite naming your variable `element`, it's actually the index, not the element at that index.

You can tell that because you have to use `myList[element]` to compare it.

So, to fix it, do the same thing again:

```
nList.append(myList[element])
```

However, there's a much simpler way to do this: Just loop over the elements directly.

```
nList = []
for element in nList:
    if option == 0:
        if element > 5:
            nList.append(element)
return nList
```

You almost *never* want to loop over `range(len(spam))`. Usually, you just want the elements, so just loop over `spam` itself. Sometimes you need the indexes *and* the elements, so loop over `enumerate(spam)`. If you really just need the indexes… step back and make sure you really do (often people think they want this only because they don't know about `zip`, or because they're trying to make changes in-place instead of copying, but doing it in a way that won't work).

Or, even more simply:

```
if option != 0:
    return []
return [element for element in nList if element > 5]
```

---

Meanwhile:

> I want it too return the values of 7 and 8 and also -6 but I know I don't have the right code to return -6 as of now.

You can translate your English directly into Python:

> it will return numbers that are greater than 5 or less than -5

… is:

```
… element > 5 or element < -5 …
```

However, there's a way to write this that's simpler, if you understand it:

```
… abs(element) > 5 …
```

---

So, this gets option 0 to work. What about option 1?

One simple way to tell if a number is odd is if `number % 2` is non-zero.

So, let's put it all together:

```
if option == 0:
    return [element for element in nList if abs(element) > 5]
elif option == 1:
    return [element for element in nList if element % 2]
else:
    raise ValueError("I don't know option {}".format(option))
```

---

From a comment:

> How would I change this to a while loop?

To change a `for` loop into a `while` loop, you have to break it into three parts: initialize the loop variable, write a `while` test, and update the loop variable inside the body. The general translation is this:

```
for element in iterable:
    spam(element)

it = iterator(iterable)
while True:
    try:
        element = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    else:
        spam(element)
```

Ugly, isn't it? But usually, you can come up with something simpler that's specific to your case. For example, if the iterable is a sequence, list a `list`, you can do this:

```
index, size = 0, len(sequence)
while index < size:
    spam(sequence[index])
    index += 1
```

Still not nearly as nice as the `for` loop, but not nearly as ugly as the generic `while`.

---

Finally, just for fun. Everyone knows that function mappings are more Pythonic than `elif` chains, right? To prove the value of dogmatically following rules like that, let's do it here:

```
preds = {0: lambda x: abs(x) > 5,
         1: lambda x: x % 2}
def splitList(myList, option):
    return filter(preds[option], myList)
```

Comment: May as well add the odd number filter on `option == 1` while you're at it?

Comment: @IskarJarak: Sure, why not.

Comment: @IskarJarak: I keep getting options 0 and 1 mixed up. (This is why we have enums…) Can you check it over and make sure I've got it right now?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and was going to say something, but your last edit before adding the lambda/filter ugliness has it all fixed.

Comment: it is just returning brackets [], not numbers in the brackets when you choose option 0, haven't tried option 1 yet.

Comment: @RyanErickson Assuming you are using the section below _"So, let's put it all together:"_ that should only be the case if no numbers fulfil the condition. I get `[-6, 7, 8]` for `splitList([-6,4,7,8,3], 0)`

Comment: Sorry about that, I put something else in it.  I got it correct now for that part.

Comment: @IskarJarak: The lambda/filter ugliness is partly to help out teachers (any student who turns that in clearly copied, pasted, tested, and turned in code without even trying to understand it)… but mostly just for fun. A function mapping is more Pythonic than an `ifelse` chain, right? :)

Comment: How would I change this to a while loop? @abarnert

Comment: @RyanErickson: I'm not sure why you'd want to change it to a `while` loop, but I'll edit the answer to show you two ways to do it.

Comment: Haha, don't worry, I have no problem with you adding it to your answer, and I didn't mean to come across that way.

Comment: @abarnert I'm still struggling to understand what you did for the while loop.  where did you put this in?  I tried coding this and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @RyanErickson: Either `while` loop replaces the `for` loop. Obviously your `for` loop doesn't have `spam(element)` as the body; put the actual body in its place. Just notice that `spam(element)` in the `for` was turned into `spam(sequence[index])` in the `while`; you have to do that transformation everywhere—or, maybe more simply, add a line `element = sequence[index]` at the very top of the `while` body so you don't have to change anything else.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include what it would look like with my function in it?  I'm sorry I just don't really understand it over words.

Comment: @RyanErickson: I'm not going to do all of your work for you. Especially as a followup to a question that already has an answer that's this long; adding even more to it will just make it less useful for future readers. On top of that, I already explained what was wrong with your version in a comment on the question. If you can't understand that after reading this answer, you're not going to be able to understand the code I'd give you. You may get a passing grade on this assignment by turning in code you don't get, but you're going to fail the class anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should just write two separate functions, since the function you're trying to add options to does rather different things.

Python lets you iterate over lists and other data structures easily:

```
for element in myList:
    if option == 0:
        if element > 5:
            nList.append(element)
    ....
```

Comment: How would i switch this to a while loop? @decency

Comment: @RyanErickson I wouldn't, but you can always create a variable to increment as you iterate over the list in each while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because one-liners are fun:

```
def splitlist(li, flag):
    return [x for x in li if x%2==1] if flag else [x for x in li if abs(x)>5]
```

If this is homework, you probably don't want to be turning in this for an answer, but it should give some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Other aspects of the question have been ably answered, but there's a rather unpythonic construction in your argument use. Better would be:

```
def extract_elements(my_list, odd_only):
    """Return select elements from my_list.

    If odd_only is True return the odd elements. 
    If odd_only is False return elements between -5 and 5 inclusive.
    """
    …
```

There are four significant points demonstrated here:

1. Names are very important, `odd_only` is far more descriptive than `option`, and calling a method `splitList` when it doesn't split anything is confusing to read.
2. Don't use arbitrary integers to represent a boolean option when the language has intrinsic booleans.
3. There is no name for that method that could possibly allow the reader to understand its highly idiosyncratic function (and `extract_odd_or_magnitude_of_five` is hard to type and *still* isn't descriptive). That's why there are [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), they bind the description of the method very closely to the method definition.
4. Convention matters. The [Style Guide for Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) helps others read your code.